# Different names of parents in passport Proof of relationship UK visa

Tags: uk, passports, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to apply for a standard visitor visa for my father, the problem is the name of my father in my passport and the name in his passport are different. We used to have a different surname long ago when I applied for my 15 years ago I got my passport with our new surname but since my parents didn't have their documents with new surname, my parent's name was written with the old surname, then during reissue, it wasn't changed 5 years ago and now they have got their surname change in documents and their passport contains new surname that matches my surname but not the one surname mentioned in my passport.

for e.g in my passport father's name is: `C XYZ ABC`
and in my father's passport, the name is: `XYZ QWE`

I'll write `C XYZ ABC` in the form question that asks have you ever been known by any other name? is there anything else I can do to show he is my father?